# Returning values URLSession.shared.dataTask in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I just started coding in `Swift` and I have the following code which parses JSON

```
func parse (latitude: Double, longtitude: Double){


    let jsonUrlString = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/apiKey/\(latitude),\(longtitude)"

    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else{
        return
    }

    var information: forecast?
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, res, err) in

        guard let data = data else { 
              return
        }

        do {
            let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(forecast.self, from: data)
            self.info = json

        } catch {
            print("didnt work")
        }

    }.resume()

    processJson(info)
}
```

My problem is that I want to pass data that is stored in JSON to a variable in the class to be processed using `processJson` function but since the dataTask function does not return any values, and JSON variable is locally stored I cannot process info variable outside the class (it always returns nil). I was wondering what is the solution to this problem? I'm facing the same problem with `weather.getCoordinate()`.

Comment: Your Secret Key must be required for API calling in Darksky
so, you read Document for add your Secret key: darksky.net/dev/docs 
example : https://api.darksky.net/forecast/[yoursecretkey]/37.8267,-122.4233

Comment: Yea, I do have an API. I just removed so no one can use it here. Thanks though

Comment: You're using `URLSession` to make your request to the API, but `URLSession` make the call to the API asynchronously so the response of the request is handled using closures, this means that the line after the `resume` you're setting doesn't work at all because it will be called before the request finish and you variable is set. You should move it after set the variable in the closure

Comment: I tried that, but still can't access the data outside the function. here is what I did:

            do{
                let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(forecast.self, from: data)
                print (json)
                self.info = json
                print("information",self.info?.currently)
    func process(uiLable:UILabel) {
          print("\(self.info?.currently?.summary) •\(self.info?.currently?.temperature)")
    }
the first one prints the value, but when the second function is called it just prints nil!

Comment: here is a link to my project
[link](https://github.com/alhparsa/Weather-iOS/blob/master/json/ViewController.swift)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use completion block to return value. Add completion block your to function like this

```
func parse (latitude: Double, longtitude: Double, completion: @escaping ((AnyObject) -> Void)){
    let jsonUrlString = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/apiKey/\(latitude),\(longtitude)"

    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else{
        return
    }

    var information: forecast?
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, res, err) in

        guard let data = data else { 
              return
        }

        do {
            let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(forecast.self, from: data)
            self.info = json
            completion(info)
        } catch {
            print("didnt work")
        }

    }.resume()
```

And when you call this function, it return your info

> parse( lat, long, {info in
>       processJson(info)
>       })